# Is there a log on kafka server about consumer missing some expired offsets due to retention settings?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there a way for a kafka admin to tell if some offsets were expired before consumer managed to process and commit them, because of retention that was set on a topic, without a help from the client side logs?
There is also a question of improving the usability of kafka, by adding admin tools to its ecosystem, that are capable to extract such and similar info in an easily readable manner. Is there such a tool that can serve that info from the list of topics?

Comment: Have you looked at the LogCleaner process logs?

Comment: They appear to be cryptic to me, and googling "logcleaner logs explanation kafka" does not return a decent document that would explain how is that exactly visible in these logs. Do you have by any chance such document?

Comment: @OneCricketeer somewhat more important, could you please recommend an admin tool that is able to extract that info in a manner that can be described as a good usability? For example, you give it credentials to connect via kafka protocol plus credentials for ssh, and it combines both to report that info from the list of topics.

Comment: There is no CLI tool to inspect log segments outside the dump tool for existing logs. Once the segments are gone, nothing can tell what is/isnt there (was deleted). All I know is that we had a Splunk person in our company used those logs to show compaction and deletion events for log-segments. There is no known document that details that file (outside the source code). Sure, you could use SSH and cron to run `ls` on the topic logs directories, pair that with some cache/database and compare when things get added and removed, but the logs would obviously be "real-time"